# PDF files included with `includegraphics` and `pdfpages` don't show some pdf elements

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages, viewers

The problem is that if I make comments, text boxes, lines, etc. with a PDF viewer-editor like, in my case, *PDF Exchange Viewer*, in a PDF image to be included any of that ways, that marks don't show in the final `PDFLaTeX` output.

My knowledge about PDF format is very short, so maybe the question is about the differences between that elements and the "real", original ones. My viewer classify the first ones as "comments", and the "layers" tab is empty.

You can test it with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{pto1.pdf}
\includegraphics{./a.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PDFLaTeX strips, in general, any included files of these in-edited comments. There's a little that can be done about it. PDF specification is crazy (and likely more messy than anything e.g. Microsoft has even done), so it's very difficult for the engine to make it work. The only thing that comes to my mind: Make sure your PDF files are saved in the correct PDF version. My `pdflatex` from TeXLive2013 produces `PDF-1.4`, I suppose that this one should work the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a PDF page is included by pdfTeX (or other TeX compilers/drivers), then annotations are usually stripped (easier implementation). This means links and other annotations, added by PDF-XChange Viewer, are removed.

Project [PDFAnnotExtractor (pax)](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax) shows a way, how the annotations can be reinserted. (Currently the project is a little outdated, the number of supported annotations could be larger and it could support new [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) versions.)

Comment: And, isn't there a way to embed the lines and marks in the PDF to make them be in the same status as the original material?