# PDF file inserted with `includegraphics` does not display some PDF elements

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I got an issue very similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155997/pdf-files-included-with-includegraphics-and-pdfpages-dont-show-some-pdf-ele) one: when I insert a PDF file with `includegraphics` some elements are not displayed such as shapes (rectangles, circles, arrows, etc.) and text. Does this mean that they are considered as annotations, hence stripped out during pdflatex parsing (such as stated in the question I linked)?

I tried to edit the PDF file with several softwares (macOS preview, Adobe Acrobat and one online editor) and they are all subject to this issue, shapes are not displayed.

The question I linked is more than 7 years old, are there some new solutions to this problem? I also tried to use other vector formats (EPS, SVG) but they are not (easily) supported by pdflatex.

Comment: well probably they are annotations. It is theoretically possible to reinsert them, see https://github.com/AndreasMatthias/Flare. You could also try to print to a pdf with the comments and then insert the result.

Comment: Thanks for that promising package. Unfortunately, it only works with LuaTeX.